# Locking innodb row and get a live version

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm writing an online game, there is a section named send troops. When two or more users on one account try to send one movement the troops get doubled.

I want to get a live version of the row from mysql and prevent any read, write, update anything on that row untill I finish.

Is it actually possible? Because I sae only select for update and lock in share mode in innodb reference.

Any help is appericiated.

Comment: You'll want to use transactions.

Comment: I am using transactions with mysqli. But does it lock the row so no other process selects (reads) that row and wait?

Comment: can you have a flag column in your table showing the status of troops deployment. so that you can always check if the troops are deployed. even a user login in two different devices you can handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FROM t ... WHERE ... FOR UPDATE;
...
UPDATE t ...;
COMMIT;
```

Others can read the rows from `t`, but they will either be delayed or deadlocked if they try to modify the row(s) touched by the `SELECT`.

Do you really need to prevent all *reads* for a given row?  Please explain your scenario further.

Answer (score 0):

Please find mysql document below in order to lock a particular row in innodb:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html